# Extract Metadata from PHAsset returns unexpected nil value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, exif, phasset

I try to extract the Metadata from an PHAsset like mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450629/ios-swift-how-to-get-a-gps-metadata-from-just-a-uiimage-nsurl).

I try to extract metadata like the FocalLength or Aperture and so on.

Here is my current Code:

```
let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

phAsset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {(contentEditingInput, _) -> Void in

    let fullImage = CIImage(contentsOf: contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL!)
    let fullImageMetadata = fullImage?.properties

    if let focalLength = fullImageMetadata?[kCGImagePropertyExifFocalLength as String] {

        print(focalLength)

    }
})
```

When I use the command `po fullImageMetadata` i get the following output for my example Image:

```
▿ Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>
▿ some : 12 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "PixelHeight"
  - .1 : 2304
▿ 1 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "{JFIF}"
  ▿ .1 : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DensityUnit
      - .1 : 0
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - .0 : YDensity
      - .1 : 72
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - .0 : JFIFVersion
      ▿ .1 : 3 elements
        - 0 : 1
        - 1 : 0
        - 2 : 1
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - .0 : XDensity
      - .1 : 72
▿ 2 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "{Exif}"
  ▿ .1 : 14 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DateTimeDigitized
      - .1 : 2010:01:28 10:54:24
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ExposureProgram
      - .1 : 1
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - .0 : PixelXDimension
      - .1 : 1536
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ExposureBiasValue
      - .1 : 0
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - .0 : Flash
      - .1 : 16
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DateTimeOriginal
      - .1 : 2010:01:28 10:54:24
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      - .0 : MeteringMode
      - .1 : 3
    ▿ 7 : 2 elements
      - .0 : PixelYDimension
      - .1 : 2304
    ▿ 8 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ISOSpeedRatings
      ▿ .1 : 1 element
        - 0 : 100
    ▿ 9 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ExposureTime
      - .1 : 0.00625
    ▿ 10 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ApertureValue
      - .1 : 5.375
    ▿ 11 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ColorSpace
      - .1 : 1
    ▿ 12 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ExifVersion
      ▿ .1 : 2 elements
        - 0 : 2
        - 1 : 2
    ▿ 13 : 2 elements
      - .0 : FocalLength
      - .1 : 30
▿ 3 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "DPIWidth"
  - .1 : 72
▿ 4 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "Depth"
  - .1 : 8
▿ 5 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "ProfileName"
  - .1 : sRGB IEC61966-2.1
▿ 6 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "Orientation"
  - .1 : 1
▿ 7 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "{TIFF}"
  ▿ .1 : 8 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - .0 : ResolutionUnit
      - .1 : 2
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - .0 : Software
      - .1 : Adobe Photoshop CS3 Macintosh
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DateTime
      - .1 : 2010:04:12 16:29:18
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - .0 : XResolution
      - .1 : 72
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - .0 : Orientation
      - .1 : 1
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      - .0 : YResolution
      - .1 : 72
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      - .0 : Model
      - .1 : Canon EOS 5D Mark II
    ▿ 7 : 2 elements
      - .0 : Make
      - .1 : Canon
▿ 8 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "{IPTC}"
  ▿ .1 : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DigitalCreationTime
      - .1 : 105424+0100
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DigitalCreationDate
      - .1 : 20100128
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - .0 : DateCreated
      - .1 : 20100128
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - .0 : TimeCreated
      - .1 : 105424+0100
▿ 9 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "ColorModel"
  - .1 : RGB
▿ 10 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "DPIHeight"
  - .1 : 72
▿ 11 : 2 elements
  - .0 : "PixelWidth"
  - .1 : 1536
```

As mentioned in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450629/ios-swift-how-to-get-a-gps-metadata-from-just-a-uiimage-nsurl) I try to reach the Metadata with the `kCGImageProperty` values. But it never enters the `if`-statement an when I print the data in the debugger with `po fullImageMetadata?[kCGImageProperty[...] as String]` I get nil returned.

But somehow this needs to work or not? Can anyone see my mistake or knows what is wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve my problem with using the example from iOS with the `kCGImageProperty` variables. Instead I solved it through splitting the Dictionary into its different Parts.

To get the Exif Metadata for example I used this line of code:

```
let exifDict = fullImageMetadata?["{Exif}"] as! NSDictionary
```

and then tried to extract the properties with this code:

```
if let flash = exifDict["Flash"] as? NSNumber {
    [doing some wild stuff here]
}
```

and so on for different Properties I need to extract from the Image.